# Real-time data doesn't update on Windows web server [Python, PHP, JS, Apache]

Tags: python, php, windows, raspberry-pi3, real-time-data

I developed an intranet website that provides an interface to display real-time (300ms-1000ms updates) data for devices. My original setup is built on Raspberry PI 3Bs and has been running well for years. I used Python to capture I/O data and write an XML object to a file

EDIT: I added a bit of code that demonstrates it in a loop providing 'real-time' updates. This bit updates at 500ms. There is some additional data and a much less frequent SQL write that isn't shown.

```py
def writeXML( params, xmlFile ):
    try:
        file=open(xmlFile,"w")
        outString = "\x1B[2J" #Alternative to OS.SYSTEM('CLEAR')
        #outString = ""
        file.write("<data>\n")
        
        for p in params:
            file.write("\t<"+p[0]+">"+str(p[1])+"</"+p[0]+">\n")
            outString += p[0]+": "+str(p[1])+"\n"
        file.write("</data>\n")
        file.close()
        print(outString)
    except Exception as e:
        log.err("realtime.writeXML error - ",e)

def getStates():
    try:
        global BMEs
        for BME in BMEs:
            data = bme280.sample(BME.bus, BME.addr, BME.cal_params)
            BME.temp = round((data.temperature * 9/5)+32,2)
            BME.baro = round((data.pressure/1013),2)
            BME.humid = round(data.humidity,2)
        
            xmlParams = ([bPre+"Temp",BME.temp],[bPre+"Baro",BME.baro],[bPre+"humid",BME.humid])
            txt.writeXML(xmlParams, bmeValues)
    except Exception as e:
        log.err("bme.getStates error - ", e)

while True:
    getStates()
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

There are a few of these PIs collecting data connected on a network. My original web server is running on a PI and uses the following PHP code to read/convert the XML to a JSON object:

```php
<?php
    require_once('mapShared.php');

    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
    $mntPath = $_POST['mntPath'];
    $dirName = $_POST['dirName'];
    $remotePath = $_POST['remotePath'];
    $fileName = $_POST['fileName'];
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $pw = $_POST['pw'];

    $res = array();

    $noError = true;
    //Make the local dirName if it doesn't exist
    if ($noError) { $noError = makeDir($mntPath, $dirName); }
    //Mount the remotePath to dirName
    if ($noError) { $noError = mountDrive($mntPath, $dirName, $remotePath, $user, $pw); }
    if ($noError) {
        $fName = $mntPath.'/'.$dirName.'/'.$fileName;
        try {
            if ( filesize( $fName ) > 0 ) {
                $res=simplexml_load_file($fName, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOWARNING);
                echo json_encode($res); 
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'error';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'error';
    }
?>
```

I then use JSON.parse to convert the result into an object in JavaScript and assigned that to my real-time object (updating the data available for the page).

All of this works as expected and has for years, but I want to move the webserver to a Windows PC. I have an obsolete Win 7 machine that I dropped the javascript/PHP code into and I'm running Apache using Xampp. I modified the PHP to work with Windows mapped drives:

```php
<?php
    require_once('mapDrive.php');

    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
    $remotePath = $_POST['remotePath'];
    $fileName = $_POST['fileName'];
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $pw = $_POST['pw'];

    $res = array();

    $noError = true;
    $fName = $remotePath.'\\'.$fileName;
    if (!file_exists($fName)) { $noError = mapDrive($remotePath, $user, $pw); }
    if ($noError) {
        try {
            if ( filesize( $fName ) > 0 ) {
                $res=simplexml_load_file($fName, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOWARNING);
                echo json_encode($res); 
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'error';
        }
    }
?>
```

The problem I'm observing is that the real-time data doesn't update as expected on the Windows web site. Instead of ~3Hz, I'm hardly seeing any updates in several minutes. I still have the PI server running and I can see the values updating.

I've tried:

- Looking at the XML files manually in Windows explorer and in Raspbian. The data in the file and the modified date is changing periodically (several minutes) instead of ~3Hz. The Windows website follows this, **but the PI website updates every ~3Hz** with accurate data.
- Creating a test file in VB to tick a counter and write that to an XML file every 300ms. That updates as expected on the Windows website.
- looking at the mount folder in Raspbian. None of the XML files show up with ls. Same is true if I look with Windows Explorer, the mounted folder where the XML files should be listed. I have database files in some of these same folders, these appear normal.
- Modifying one of the python scripts to also write to a separate file in a separate folder that isn't included in a Raspbian mount. The file appears, but again doesn't update.
- Several dozen other things that weren't helpful and probably not relevant.

If the PI website wasn't updating, all the evidence would lead me to think the Python script wasn't writing the file at the intended frequency. I suspect this has something to do with the way Python is writing the file, but I've run into a block trying to figure it out.

EDIT: I can't add full content of my code (logistically and it contains potentially sensitive data) here. I added what I believe is relevant to the problem. I'll add the JS bits that get something readable in console debug:

```
function getRemote_XML(remotePath, file, user, pw, fx) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '../php/getRemoteXML.php',
        type: 'post',
        datatype: 'json',
        data: {'remotePath': remotePath,
               'fileName': file,
               'user': user,
               'pw': pw},
        success: fx,
        error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
           console.log(xhr);
           console.log("Details: " + desc + "\nError:" + err);
        }
    });
}
function rXMLtoStatus(source) { //Reads a remote XML file and converts it to an object which is written to the console [normally appended to statusData]
    let sr = source.remote;
    getRemote_XML(sr.path, source.file, sr.user, sr.password, function(data) {
        try{console.log(JSON.parse(data));}catch(e){}
        setTimeout(function(){window[source.fn](source);}, source.interval);
    });
}
```

I normally get what I need from reading questions and google search. This is my first time actually asking something. If there is a way I can improve this question, please let me know.

Comment: I don't see anything in the code that would do *"real-time"* updates.

Comment: Whatever you're seeing on your page is going to be reliant , for updates, presumably on some js code, which you haven't shown us

Comment: Welcome to SO, please check the meaning of the tags you select.  If you mouse over the "pi" tag you'll see it has nothing to do with single-board computers.

Comment: @KlausD. I may be using "real-time" incorrectly? I meant it as providing data from a source and not verifying receipt typically faster than 1Hz.  I added a little more from the Python code and the JS code to show transmission and usage.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'd imagine the speed at which the webpage gets updates will depend, in the first instance, on the value passed as `source.interval` to the `setTimeout` call - we can't see what value is passed. Obviously beyond that it would depend on the speed at which data is written to the file, where it's then read by the code in  `getRemoteXML.php` (which I assume is the last snippet of PHP you posted? You didn't provide filenames or label the scripts)

Comment: @ADyson I don't suspect that bit of code as it does read data in both environments. I did edit to add the function that makes the AJAX call, and a sample that displays the data in the console.

Comment: `I did edit to add the function that makes the AJAX call`...I know, that's what I'm primarily referring to in my comment just now

Comment: P.S. not sure what you mean by `faster than 1Hz`. It might be my ignorance but I thought Hz was a measure of wavelength frequency, not time?

Comment: @Dyson The interval for setTimeout is 500 (but can be 300-1000 depending on the data type). The interval for the python loop that writes data is the same (500 in the example). I noted that this works fine in the Raspbian website, but not in the Windows website. This is the hangup for me

Comment: 1Hz = 1 time per second

Comment: It's also worth noting faster than 300ms updates did create problems for me when I wrote the original script (~5 years ago?)

Comment: 500ms is very fast for an ajax timeout. There's a good danger of overwhelming your server, especially if a) more than one person has the page with the timeout open at once, and/or b) the server takes longer to provide a response to each request than the length interval between requests. It's possible that some version of b) is what's happening on your windows machine. You could use your browser's Network tool to analyse the ajax requests and see how long they take to respond, and whether any seem to be getting queued up or taking a long time to reply.

Comment: Since your windows machine is having to read the file over the network, that introduces extra latency and it's very possible it's taking longer to service the requests because of that, and/or the speed of the machine itself

Comment: Frankly if you're serious about making this work you need to rethink the architecture a bit - disk I/O isn't fast in any circumstance so writing and reading from a networked file is always going to slow you down. One possible improved architecture could be: the PIs write data to a websocket. The websocket server receives the inputs from the PIs and then sends the data out again in different directions - one to an always-on service which is listening and then writes the data to a log file for posterity, and 2, to any websocket clients on web pages which are listening for new updates.

Comment: That, or perhaps some variation of it based on queues / server-sent-events, even a database involved somewhere, would be more efficient and give you much more chance of getting close a real-time flow of data. Maybe do some research online too about how other IoT-style architectures for data streaming are built...it sounds like you're building a smallish version of that kind of system.

Comment: @ADyson  I know disk I/O isn't the fastest option (I think I knew this when I originally coded it). Part of the data is being read from 3rd party sources where a txt log file is the only source. Since the rest were sending fairly small packets (<1k), I just went with disk I/O for everything.

Comment: The AJAX timeout isn't the problem here. setTimeout isn't being called until after the data is received (or fails to try/catch). Using the debug console, I can see the reads come in consistently fast even on large log files from sources I can't control.

Comment: I'll modifiy to websockets if I need to, but I'd still like to understand better why Windows has problems with this where a Raspberry PI doesn't. Especially when they are reading from the same source. Based on the experiment I noted with the VB script, I'm leaning more toward the problem being with writing the file, not reading it. I can't wrap my head around how the Pi server can read changes to file that I can't see when looking manually. Maybe it's something to do how each OS handles flock during file access requests?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look at this and respond.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Is the PI website on the same machine where the XML files are stored? And what protocol is being used to share the data with windows? You could well be seeing some sort of latency due to that. P.S. Why on earth do you want to host this on a Windows machine to start with? It's not usually the choice for a system of this sort, or for Apache hosting in general (although of course it does run fine on Windows). And a test on an obsolete client-side O/S version isn't the best either - why not use a VM with your real target O/S, for example?

Comment: There are some XML files on the local machine, but most are distributed. I use a slightly different PHP for those. I don't really see a significant difference in AJAX response times between local and network (probably because the files are tiny). Converting to a Windows machine is about 'standardization'. Also, I've done this with almost no budget (hence the PIs and a salvaged obsolete machine). I basically did this to help my local situation and the people I work with love it.

Comment: It got some push to make it a corporate thing but was shut down with almost no feedback. It currently exists on a separate subnet (where a bunch of obsolete machines live) of which I have autonomy. If I had greater autonomy, I would be connecting to our reporting and scheduling systems to eliminate a lot of tedious tasks and improve our reliability.

Comment: I'm kind of worn down by the whole process of corporate speak 'this is great, this is great' then nothing. I really don't care if it gets used elsewhere, I really find it's helpful in my day-to-day. I'm just trying to anticipate someone saying 'you can't do that' for some silly reason and not having a backup option.

Comment: The PIs are using Samba for windows shares. The shares are set to browsable\writeable. I don't see anything in the smb.conf that might be limiting read/write access.

Comment: I don't think necessarily its about limiting access but potentially something in the protocol - or the implementation of it on the PI's O/S perhaps - which somehow reduces how frequently it show to Samba clients that updates to files have occurred. Or maybe something on the windows side is doing some caching which is having a similar effect. I don't know for sure, it's not an area I have any real deep knowledge of, but from the symptoms and evidence you've presented thus far, that seems to be an area to investigate more closely.

Comment: If your ajax requests to the windows server aren't slow then I can't think of another way to explain why you see updates to the files on the PI but don't see them from the Windows side as frequently

Comment: P.S. `Converting to a Windows machine is about 'standardization'`...ok, but an obsolete, client-side version of Windows certainly isn't going to be included in any corporate webserver standard, so it's a false equivalence and is not a useful test. "Windows" isn't a single homogenous thing, just like "Linux" isn't. Why not re-install this machine with a modern server O/S? Or use a VM? And also I doubt you'll be moving away from the Linux-based PIs for capturing the source data?? I get that you're not fully in control of all this but I suspect there are better ways to do it.

Comment: Anyway, regardless of the hardware and O/S situation, as I said before, I think fundamentally you aren't going to reliably get the throughput and latency you really want unless you move away from writing to the file and then reading from a file, as a means of data transfer. The files are great for _storing_ the data, and maybe accessing it later, but for real-time data throughput you're going to want to move to some sort of event-based architecture, with websockets and/or a pub/sub queue (for example)